# Can't get docker-compose networking to work

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make requests to my server container from my client app in another container. The Docker Compose docs state that the network is setup automatically, so shouldn't all ports be accessible from all containers? When I make a curl request to port 4000 from outside of the container (in a fresh terminal), it works. However when I enter the client container (`selektor-client`) and try the same request, it fails.

`curl --request POST http://localhost:4000/api/music`

What am I doing wrong?

*docker-compose.yaml:*

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    container_name: selektor-client
    restart: always
    build: ./client 
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/client/
      - /client/node_modules/
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
  server:
    container_name: selektor-server
    restart: always
    build: ./server 
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/server/
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
  mongo:
    container_name: selektor-mongo
    command: mongod --noauth
    build: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Comment: What URL or host name are you trying to call?  From where?  What error do you get?

Comment: @DavidMaze `curl  --request POST http://localhost:4000/api/music` ...calling it from regular terminal works (I have a console.log in the endpoint), but calling from within the selektor-client container returns `Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused`

Comment: Each container is its own `localhost`, so when you try to make that call from within the client container it tries to go to port 4000 of the client container.  You can use the Compose service name `server` as a host name.  There's more details on what's readily available in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: Ah got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you call containers of the same stack each other, the host name is, by default, the service name, and the port is the internal port: `<servicename>:<internal_port>`. So, based on this part of your example:

```
version: "3"
  server:
    container_name: selektor-server
    restart: always
    build: ./server 
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/server/
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
```

The url you client have to use to reach the server is `http://server:4000`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem . my solution was registering network and giving subnet mast to the network  and register the static ip to each container :

```
version: "3"
networks: 
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
services:
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:4.2.1
      container_name: mongo
      command: mongod --auth
      hostname: mongo
      networks: 
        my_network:
          ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
      volumes:
        - /data/db/mongo:/data/db
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    rabitmq:
      hostname: rabbitmq
      container_name: rabbitmq
      image: rabbitmq:latest
      networks: 
        my_network:
          ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
      volumes:
        - /var/lib/rabbitmq:/data/db
      ports:
        - "5672:5672"
        - "15672:15672"
      restart: always
```

you can access through IP addresses

Comment: This level of manual setup is rarely necessary.  The Docker-private IP addresses are generally an implementation detail, and they're only reachable outside of Docker space on one very specific host setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze tnx, I know. this question was my problem once. I could not find any better solution . so I tried to register my own network(bridge type) and give static ip addresses to them .